# Nvidia drivers are no longer working on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 20.04, nvidia

Today my nvidia-driver-525 stopped working in Ubuntu 22.04. I tried reinstalling using the *Additional drivers* and by CLI command `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-525`, but in vain.

I have the following information. Just ask for other information if you would need it to diagnose my problem:

- Lenovo laptop
- Results of `lspci | grep VGA` >

  ```
  01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107GLM [Quadro P2000 Mobile] (rev a1)
  ```
- Results of `sudo lshw -C video :

```
*-display
    description: VGA compatible controller
    product: GP107GLM [Quadro P2000 Mobile]
    vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
    logical name: /dev/fb0
    version: a1
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
    configuration: depth=32 driver=nouveau latency=0 resolution=3840,2160
    resources: irq:190 memory:a3000000-a3ffffff memory:60000000-6fffffff
    memory:70000000-71ffffff ioport:2000(size=128) memory:a4080000-a40fffff
```

Currently I use the open source driver which has no acceleration and is only usable when I only use 1 display (internal or external monitor).

Comment: The driver is not installed. Is Secure Boot disabled?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: Hi, secure boot is active. I have a dual boot with Windows 11 and fear that I won't be able to launch windiws after deactivating secure boot.

Here is the output:
$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display' 
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107GLM [Quadro P2000 Mobile] (rev a1)
 Subsystem: Lenovo GP107GLM [Quadro P2000 Mobile]
 Kernel driver in use: nouveau
 Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau